# How to enable Docker Build Context in azure machine learning studio?

Tags: python, docker, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

I'm trying to create an environment from a custom Dockerfile in the UI of Azure Machine Learning Studio. It previously used to work when I used the option: Create a new Docker context.

I decided to do it through code and build the image on compute, meaning I used this line to set it:

```
ws.update(image_build_compute = "my_compute_cluster")
```

But now I cannot create any environment through the UI and the docker build context anymore. I tried setting back the property `image_build_compute` to `None` or `False` but it doesn't work either.
Also tried deleting the property through the cli but also doesn't work. I checked on another machine learning workspace and this property doesn't exists.

Is there a way for me to completely remove this property or enable again the docker build context?

Answer (score 0):

Created compute cluster with some specifications and there is a possibility to update the version of the cluster and checkout the code block.

[image]

```
workspace.update(image_build_compute = "Standard_DS12_v2")
```

We can create the compute instance using the UI of the portal using the following steps using the docker.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

With the above procedure we can get to confirm that the environment was created using the docker image and file.